# Riemann sum proof that if an integral of a non-negative function is $0$ than the function is $0$.

Tags: calculus, riemann-sum

Basically what the title says. I'm aware of other proof techniques that can be used to prove the question.

**Question:** Suppose that $f$ is a continuous function on $[a,b]$ and that $f(x)≥0$ for all $x∈[a,b]$. Show that if $∫^b_af(x)=0$, then $f(x)=0$ for all $x∈[a,b]$.

**Solution:** Define an equidistant partition $\tau = \{x_k|k=0,\ldots,n\}$, $x_k=a+\frac{k(b-a)}{n}$, $\Delta x_k=\frac{b-a}{n}$.

My sum is equal to $$\sum^{n}_{k=1}f(x_k)\Delta x_k=\sum^{n}_{k=1}[f(a+\frac{k(b-a)}{n})\frac{b-a}{n}]=\frac{b-a}{n}\sum^{n}_{k=1}f(a+\frac{k(b-a)}{n})\stackrel{!}{=}0$$

Finally, my plan was to evaluate the limit of the sum and to show that if $n \rightarrow \infty$ then $f=0$ at every point of the interval $[a,b]$. Do I have to additionally prove that the function is constant and use this fact to factor it out of the sum? It seems very unelegant. Maybe I'm missing something.

Comment: I'm a bit confused why you would need to find a limit or see behavior as $n$ approached infinity. You broke it up into finite parts as is the goal of a riemann sum.

Comment: @DerekLuna I was thinking that a finite sum may very well be not equal to 0, so I have to find a limit because the limit of the sum is equal to the integral which in turn is equal to 0. Hope you understand what I mean. Otherwise I'll probably just use finite sum and mention that since the function is non-negative, none of it's finite sums can be positive and the function itself has to be 0.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure how much is going to go through without using a proof by contrapositive since any partition you make needs to have a finite number of elements and if you index a sum by the set $\{0,...,n\}$ we don't get information about every $f(x)$, only those $f(x_{k})$ where $k$ is in the index set $\{0,...,n\}$. If you suppose for some $x$ we have $f(x) > 0$ and then create a simple tagged partition where one of your partition elements will be $> 0$ and all the others will be $\geq 0$, then you will eventually get that $∫^b_af(x) > 0$. Your specific approach will not work because all you can prove is that those specific $f(x_{k}) = 0$ and also there is no limiting business for $n$ since $n$ is fixed from the start.

Comment: I accepted your answer since in the end I decided to create a partition where one of the $x_k$ is explicitly $>0$.

Comment: How do you use the continuity of $ f $ in this solution?  If $ f $ is discontinuous, the statement is false.  ( $ f $ can be non-zero at a singular point and still have Riemann integral zero )

Comment: By hypothesis $f$ is continuous which implies $f$ is riemann integrable and that we can create any tagged partition. So then one can create this equidistant partition, divide out this constant and end up with the sum of all the$ f(x_{k})$.

Comment: @DerekLuna but the example I gave above is also Riemann integrable, because its discontinuity set has measure zero.  Literally everything you wrote in your post would apply to my function with a removable singularity, but the conclusion that $ f(x) \equiv 0 $ would not follow.  So the important details are somewhere in the handwaving you did at the end.

Comment: I am confused what you are arguing with me about. The only thing different between our posts is that you explicitly wrote out the delta argument.

Comment: It doesn't seem handwavy at all to me. Because of $f$'s Riemann Integrability the problem can be translated to one concerning a finite sum almost immediately.

Comment: There is a part where I wrote incorrectly that one reaches a contradiction of the hypothesis (It is the hypothesis of the original statement of the problem, but not when one is trying to prove the statement by contrapositve). What I really meant has been edited in. Maybe this is what you were referring to.

Answer (score 1):

This is a perfect problem for proving the *contrapositive*.   Suppose $ f $ is non-negative but *not* identically zero, and show that the integral is positive.  To accomplish this, let $ x_0 $ be any point where $ f(x_0) = y_0 > 0 $.  By continuity, there exists $ \delta $ such that $ f(x) > y_0 / 2 > 0 $ for all $ x $ with $ |x - x_0| < \delta $.  Now consider any Riemann sum with $ \|\Delta\| < \delta $ and you can see that $ R_*(f, \Delta) > \delta y_0 / 2 $.  Hence the integral itself is greater than or equal to $ \delta y_0 / 2 $.  Does this argument work for you?